# Deriving masses after spontaneous symmetry breaking with a field in a peculiar representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking

I am attempting to break the Pati-Salam group $SU(4)_{c'} \times SU(2)_L\times SU(2)_R$ with a field $\psi$ that fits in the following representation: $(4,\bar 2,1)$. My objective is to derive the masses of the massive gauge bosons that arise from this breaking. 
As usual, I compute the covariant derivative:

$
D_\mu \psi=\partial _\mu \psi -ig_4G_\mu \psi + ig_R \psi\; W_\mu ^R$

where $ G_\mu= \frac{G_\mu^i\lambda^i}{\sqrt {6}} $ and $W_\mu ^R=W_{\mu\;i} ^R \frac{\sigma^i}{2}$. The $\lambda^i$ are the generators of  $SU(4)_{c'} $ and the $\sigma ^i$ are the generators of  $ SU(2)_R$. For example, if I want to leave the $SU(3)$ gluons massless, I can use the following vev:

$<\psi> = \begin{pmatrix}(0\;\;0)\\(0\;\;0)\\(0\;\;0)\\(0\;\;\nu) \end{pmatrix}$

Now, in order to derive masses, I want to evaluate $|D_\mu \psi|^2|_{\psi=<\psi>}$. My problem is the following: from the point of view of $SU(4)_{c'}$, $\psi$ is a vector, from the point of view of $SU(2)_R$, $\psi$ is a covector. The norm squared (or modulus squared) of a vector is $\psi ^\dagger \psi$, the norm squared of a covector is $\psi \psi^\dagger$. I don't know how to obtain $|D_\mu \psi|^2|_{\psi=<\psi>}$. If I compute $(D_\mu \psi)^\dagger(D^\mu \psi)|_{\psi=<\psi>}$ then I run into some problems when trying to evaluate $\psi^\dagger \psi |_{\psi=<\psi>}$ because of the covector nature of $\psi$.

How can I solve this problem? Is this a special case where I should I not be evaluating $|D_\mu \psi|^2|_{\psi=<\psi>}$ in this manner? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properly written kinetic term for matrix-valued fields is
$$ \text{Tr}\Big((D_\mu\psi)^\dagger (D^\mu\psi)\Big)$$
If you use this expression it doesn't matter in which order you multiply them, as the trace is cyclic.

Comment: thank you very much, this has been bugging me for days!